# Is it violating Music Stack Exchange rules to ask "Who is the singer of this lyrics?"?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have received a miscellaneous clip that its author had mixed a piece of music (~ 40 seconds) with some pictures. I extracted the music from the clip and already have recognized the singer of the music track, but identifying the lyrics is very hard because the track's quality is very low.

Can I ask a question to identify track details (which concert/album) by giving (possibly wrong) understood words of the lyrics? or even by giving that trimmed file of the track?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this would be off-topic here.  See https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic:

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> **Music: Practice & Theory** Stack Exchange is for musicians, students, and enthusiasts. If you have a question [that] is not about...
>
> - [...]
> - genre categorization or other concerns from the perspective of a listener rather than a musician (try [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) instead)
> - [...]
> - identifying a song, style/genre, instrument/equipment, technique, chord progression, etc.

Our sister site Music Fans has an [identify-this-song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song) tag, but you should review their requirements before posting there.